# How to pass data from tableview controller to another view controller in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am new programming in objective c for mac os, I have a code that connects to an api and displays the information of this api (json) in an NSTableview. Now what I want to do is pass the data from a table cell when a cell is clicked, pass it to another new viewcontroller and show the information that was clicked on the table in this new view controller.

This is the code that I use to put the data in the table:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

_climas = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self CargarDatos];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


-(void) CargarDatos{
[_climas removeAllObjects];

AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

//Entradas y salidas
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    
[self InicializarProgress];
[manager GET:@"https://serviciorestismael.azurewebsites.net/weatherforecast"
  parameters:nil
     headers:nil
    progress:nil
     success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task,id responseObject){
    
    self -> datosJson = (NSDictionary *) responseObject;
    
    for (NSObject* key in self ->datosJson){
        
        Clima *clima = [[Clima alloc] init];
        [clima setClimaId:(NSString *)[key valueForKey:@"climaId"]];
        [clima setClimaSummary:(NSString *)[key valueForKey:@"climaSummary"]];
        [clima setClimaDate:(NSString *)[key valueForKey:@"climaDate"]];
        [clima setClimaTemperatureC:(NSString *)[key valueForKey:@"climaTemperatureC"]];
        [clima setClimaTemperatureF:(NSString *)[key valueForKey:@"climaTemperatureF"]];
        
        [self->_climas addObject:clima];
    }
    //Esperar 5 segundos
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:5.0f];
    [self->_Tabla reloadData];
    [self FinalizarProgress];
}
     failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * operation, NSError *error) {
    
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [self FinalizarProgress];

}];

}

//MARK: NSTableViewDataSoruce
- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView{
return [_climas count];
}

- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn 
*)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{
Clima *p = [_climas  objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
NSString *columna = [p valueForKey:identifier];
return columna;
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn: 
(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
if(tableView == self.Tabla)
{
    if (row == [tableView editedRow] && [[tableView tableColumns] indexOfObject:tableColumn] == [tableView editedColumn])
        {
         NSLog(@"cell string value is %@",[cell stringValue]);
        }
}
}
```

Comment: "a table cell when a cell is clicked"  WHERE in your code?

Comment: what I mean is that when a cell of the table is clicked, the information of this cell is passed to another viewcontroller

Comment: Where are you selecting a cell?  And send what to which view controller?

Comment: @ElTomato I still don't have that part of the code, since I still don't know how to implement it

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+nsviewcontroller+pass+data

Answer (score 0):

**Starting Out?**

If you're just starting with iOS/Mac development or Apple is your first programming stack, maybe start with [Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter). This is the [first tutorial hit](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/broadcasting-with-nsnotification-center-8bc0ccd2f5c3), today in Google. It looks alright.

**Beyond Basics**

When you are comfortable with that there are many other approaches which can fit into architectural considerations. Things like FRP (RxCococa, Combine) or dependency injection (one controller references another) or multi-cast delegates. For these you can Google up some tutorials, try it out and post a specific question. Just for the basics, start with Notifications.

Comment: iOS?  Nope.  See the tags.

Comment:  Updated. The answer still applies. Also updated the tutorial for ObjC.

Comment: So does it help? Are you following?